# iron.io queue system sends emails infinitely

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, iron.io

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and the iron.io version 4  , I use the queue to send emails 
and also I configured a supervisor to avoid typing php artisan queue:listen 
now the problem is in the log file (storage/logs) I get an error message

```
 [IronCore\HttpException]                                  
  http error: 400 | {"msg":"A reservation_id is required"}
```

and the email get sended infinitely every minute , what to do to stop sending emails ? please I need your help guys

Comment: How about checking the number of attempts? Check the http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues - Checking The Number Of Run Attempts . You can check if the number of attempts is less then 2 inside an if statement and only then release the job.

Comment: Looks like you're using IronMQ v3 which requires an updated lib, which is on the v3 branch right now: https://github.com/iron-io/iron_mq_php/tree/v3

Comment: @Travis No I'm using version 4 as I mentioned above

Comment: @khaleader, the following links could help you: https://github.com/iron-io/iron_mq_php/tree/v4#reserve-a-message and https://github.com/iron-io/iron_mq_php/tree/v4#delete-a-message-from-the-queue . Pay attention   at reservation_id parameter.

Comment: And also please ensure you are working with v3 version of IronMq (default is v2). You can find MQv2 and MQv3 buttons at hud at projects list page.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Iron mq php](https://github.com/iron-io/iron_mq_php) the recommended version of Iron MQ for Laravel 5.1 is 4.*. There is a commit [by Ryantology](https://github.com/ryantology/framework/commit/5c62b654c3931a4482918da85a3ed3f6a698ea91) that adds the `reservation_id` to `deleteMessage` method.

It only involves changing three lines.

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to use [this](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/iron-queue) Laravel driver for IronMQ. It's designed for different Laravel versions including 5.1.

Comment: Maybe read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and give some more context to your answer